# Python os.open is not working in ubuntu

Tags: python

I am using python 3.6 on ubuntu-18.04. I wrote a python script to play songs. Here is a part of the code:

```
elif 'play song' in query:
        songs_dir = '/home/mjiabir/Music/mp3'
        songs = os.listdir(songs_dir)
        os.open(os.path.join(songs_dir, songs[0]),os.O_RDONLY)
```

When I enter this command, it takes the command and does nothing, just avoids it and asks for the next command. What should I do?

Comment: It does [exactly what it should](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open). The big question is what *you* want to do with the file - os.open is probably not what you're looking for. It's meant for low-level file operation.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html:  "*If you just want to read or write a file see open()*" (not os.open())

Comment: @vidarlo I give it a command through voice. It listens and then it should open the mp3 file and run it. Isn't that the thing, it should do? If not, then can you please tell me, what code should  I write to run an mp3 file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open doesn't mean it will play. Use below code for play music . maybe little tweak required.

```
from pygame import mixer  # Load the popular external library

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('e:/LOCAL/Betrayer/Metalik Klinik1-Anak Sekolah.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
```

Refer & credit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021457/playing-mp3-song-on-python